# Php function/define html code

Tags: php, html

In my code i would like to define a function / variable / ... .

It should look like something like this:

```
<?php

//define something here
{
 "html code inside here"
}

// some php code

if(...)
{
 "output the html
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: *"It should look like something like this"* - It does look that. *"How can I do this?"* - Do what exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to put it in a variable/function first, or echo out the html below.

Option #1:

```
$html = "This is test html <a href='http://google.com'>google</a>";

if ( !empty($_POST) )
{
    echo $html;
}
```

Option #2:

```
if ( !empty($_POST) )
{
     echo "This is test html <a href='http://google.com'>google</a>";
     //Or simply:
     ?>
     This is test html <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
     <?php
}
```

Option #3:

```
function outputHtml() {
     ?>
     This is test html <a href="http://google.com">google</a>
     <?php
}

if ( !empty($_POST) )
{
      outputHtml();
}
```

Comment: I got it right, but forgot the "()". Thanks a lot!

Comment: If my answer worked for you, please remember to mark it as answered (Using the green checkmark).

Comment: I need to wait 10 minutes after your post  :3